# Template keys {{ prev_data_interval_end_success }} equals {{ dag_run.execution_date }} for some airflow DAG runs

Tags: airflow

I am working through a problem where I cannot get DAGs to run on the correct data interval.

The DAGs are of the form:

```
CYCLE_START_SECONDS = 240
CYCLE_END_SECONDS = 120


@dag(schedule_interval=timedelta(seconds=CYCLE_START_SECONDS - CYCLE_END_SECONDS), start_date=datetime(2021, 11, 16),
 catchup=True, default_args=DEFAULT_ARGS,
 on_failure_callback=emit_on_task_failure, max_active_runs=1, on_success_callback=emit_on_dag_success,
 render_template_as_native_obj=True)
def ETL_Workflow():
"""
Workflow to post process raw data into metrics for ingest into ES
:return:
"""

@task()
def get_start_date(start, end):
    print(start, end)
    end = int(end.timestamp())
    if isinstance(start, pendulum.DateTime):
        start = int(start.timestamp())
    else:
        start = end - CYCLE_START_SECONDS
    return start, end

@task(execution_timeout=timedelta(seconds=CYCLE_START_SECONDS - CYCLE_END_SECONDS))
def run_query(start_end: tuple, query_template, conn_str, redis_key, transforms):
    start, end = start_end
    query = query_template.format(start=start, end=end)
    return run_pipeline(query, conn_str, redis_key, transforms)

@task()
def store_period_end(start_end: tuple):
    _ = Variable.set(DAG_NAME + "_period_end", start_end[1])
    return

start = '{{ prev_data_interval_end_success }}'
end = '{{ dag_run.execution_date }}'

conn_str = get_source_url(SECRET)
start_end = get_start_date(start, end)
t1 = run_query(start_end, QUERY, conn_str, REDIS_KEY, TRANSFORMS)
t3 = store_period_end(start_end)
start_end >> t1 >> t3


dag = ETL_Workflow()
```

Specifically, I get the desired data intervals using these templates:

```
start = '{{ prev_data_interval_end_success }}'
end = '{{ dag_run.execution_date }}'
```

But then for some reason those values resolve to the same datetime

```
[2021-12-04, 18:42:20 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:109} INFO - start: 2021-12-04T18:40:18.451905+00:00 end: 2021-12-04 18:40:18.451905+00:00
```

You can see, however, that the data intervals are correct in the run metadata:

[image: run info]

I am stumped. The DAG execution date should be CYCLE_START_SECONDS after the previous run's data interval end. I have unit tested the logic in get_start_date and it is fine. Moreover, some workflows don't experience this problem. For those workflows, the execution datetime correctly works out to CYCLE_START_SECONDS after the previous data interval end. Am I using the templates incorrectly? Am I specifying the schedule incorrectly? Any pointers as to what might be the problem would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you’re misunderstanding `execution_date` (which is normal because it’s a freaking confusing concept). A DAG run’s `execution_date` is NOT when the run happens, but when the data it should process started to come in. For an interval-scheduled DAG, `execution_date` almost always equals to `data_interval_start`, which in turn almost always equals to its previous DAG run’s `data_interval_end`. This means that `execution_date` *is* the previous run’s `data_interval_end`, not an interval after. Therefore, if the previous run succeeds, you see `prev_data_interval_end_success` equal to `execution_date`. It’s entirely normal.

Given you know the existence of prev_data_interval_end_success, you likely also know that `execution_date` is deprecated, and it’s exactly because the concept is way too confusing. Do not use it when writing new DAGs; you are probably looking for `data_interval_end` instead.

Comment: Thanks. Switching to data_interval_end fixed the issue, though I had to add an offset to avoid querying data that had not been filled from upstream pipelines.